# SilverStripe calendar validation error

Tags: php, silverstripe

I am using SilverStripe 3.2.1.

When I create a new event inside the calendar page type I get an error from the recursion tab (even if I don't touch the recursion tab). The error says that I have to select one of the available options and only after the event is created.

I want to skip this recursion validation error.

[image]

After some research I found the problem is the following fields in the `CalendarEvent` `getCMSFields()`:

- `CustomRecursionType`
- `MonthlyRecursionType1`
- `MonthlyRecursionType2`

If I comment out these fields I can create and update the page, but I don't want to remove these fields.

I have tried to catch the value from these fields with `onBeforeWrite()` but I still get the validation error. This means that this validation is taking place before this, but I don't know what function I should use to hook into the result.

Another thing I have seen is the inner div has the `id` `Form_EditForm_Recursion_Holder`, which in another installation is only `Recursion`. I have changed this `id` inside the `calendar_cms.js` but still no luck.

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: With 3.2 there is a bug with the option set fields if I remember correctly. Basically they won't validate correctly if you have set them required > upgrading to 3.4 should if fix the issues or override the module so that those aren't required. Basically the optionsets were missing some method regarding validation.

Comment: Yeah, maybe it's a but, but it's strange becouse i have googled a lot, and seems that i'm the first one with this issue. it's not required. Do u know if there's another function that take's place before the "onBeforeWrite()" right after click on "Save/Publish" ? Thanks for help

Comment: You have been googling probably with the wrong terms them :).  Upgrading to 3.4 fixes UDF option validation issues https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-userforms/issues/497  so I'd presume it would fix the issues on that also. And upgrading 3.4.x isn't as problematic as upgrading to 3.2  was as you have that. So I'd suggest on trying that as it´s just matter of installing the correct version of silverstripe.

Comment: ok.. i will try to update it. Thank you. So maybe the most quick thing i can do for the moment is to disable the fields, right ?

Comment: I'd assume so, or tweak the validation if possible. But if you can try 3.4 on a vagrant box for example and if that section works we can close this question with a legimite answer even if you do something else. Just to be sure. You are running this https://github.com/unclecheese/silverstripe-event-calendar have you updated that as there are some 3.2 fixes in the repo?

Comment: I came across this issue with the event calendar in SilverStripe 3.2 earlier this year. I made a pull request that fixed up this and other issues to get it to work: https://github.com/unclecheese/silverstripe-event-calendar/pull/99  Make sure you have the latest version of the the event calendar module.